# Exporting date fields from Cognito Forms to Excel on Mac transforms date by 4 years

Tags: cognito-forms, microsoft-excel

Why, when I export the entries to Excel, does it change date by 4 years and 1 day and how do I avoid it?

For example, 18/11/2017 on the screen becomes 19/11/2021 in the Excel version. Please note we work with a date format of dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your Excel is set to the 1904 date system (more likely for Mac users than PC users). This is an Excel option. Dates in Excel are index numbers that by convention start either in 1900 or 1904.

The setting may be changed in Excel under Options > Advanced > When calculating this workbook.

Comment: Yes I am on a Mac and it was set to 1904. I have learnt something today. I appreciate your help. Thank you